# Comprehensive list of grammar rules?

Tags: grammar, rules

Does anyone know of a near-comprehensive list of grammar rules? (Specifically those which a poor writer of English might violate.)

The most amusing candidate I've found was http://www.listsofnote.com/2012/01/fumblerules-of-grammar.html but that doesn't count ;)

Comment: The best I've found so far is http://thecriticalreader.com/general-grammar-tips/sat-grammar/item/264-complete-sat-grammar-rules.html

Comment: If you really **do** mean English grammar rules (and not just another catechism of shibboleths), [try this list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf). It's only preliminary, but it's got over 200 syntactic rules.

Comment: Jim McCawley battles the Catechisms of Shibboleths. Is it in 3-D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ***Try these two websites. They may be helpful.***

[www.edufind.com](http://www.edufind.com/)

[www.grammarbook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com)